# Tuple "upcasting" in Swift

Tags: swift, casting, tuples, swift2

If I have a tuple with signature `(String, Bool)` I cannot cast it to `(String, Any)`. The compiler says:

> error: cannot express tuple conversion '(String, Bool)' to '(String,
>   Any)'

But this should work since `Bool` can be casted safely to `Any` with `as`. Almost the same error gets thrown if you do something like that:

```
let any: Any = ("String", true)
any as! (String, Any) // error
any as! (String, Bool) // obviously succeeds
```

error:

> Could not cast value of type '(Swift.String, Swift.Bool)' to
>   '(protocol<>, protocol<>)'

So is there any workaround especially for the second scenario? Because you cannot even cast `Any` to any tuple `(Any, Any)` where you could cast the elements separately.

Comment: Well, there's the ugly `((any as! (String, Bool)).0 , (any as! (String, Bool)).1 as Any)` which results in a tuple of type `(String, Any)`.

Comment: This works if you know that `any` is in reality of type `(String, Bool)` so the cast succeeds. But I only know that `any` is of type `Any` what should I do?

Comment: My sincere advice is to stay away from `Any`. There's always a better way.

Comment: I know `Any` is kind of evil in a static language. So this is not production code :) But I wondered how to get around this problem since some APIs still use `AnyObject`.

Comment: APIs which use `AnyObject` are based on Objective-C which doesn't work with tuples anyway, so you're not going to receive a tuple such as `(AnyObject, AnyObject)` from one of those APIs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tuples cannot be cast, even if the types they contain can. For example:

```
let nums = (1, 5, 9)
let doubleNums = nums as (Double, Double, Double) //fails
```

But:

```
let nums : (Double, Double, Double) = (1, 5, 9) //succeeds
```

The workaround in your case is to cast the individual element, not the Tuple itself:

```
let tuple = ("String", true)
let anyTuple = (tuple.0, tuple.1 as Any)
// anyTuple is (String, Any)
```

This is one of the reasons [the Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID329) notes:

> Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They are not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple.

I think this is an implementation limitation because Tuples are *compound types* like functions. Similarly, you cannot create extensions of Tuples (e.g. `extension (String, Bool) { … }`).

---

If you're actually working with an API that returns `(String, Any)`, try to change it to use a class or struct. But if you're powerless to improve the API, you can `switch` on the second element's type:

```
let tuple : (String, Any) = ("string", true)

switch tuple.1 {

case let x as Bool:
    print("It's a Bool")
    let boolTuple = (tuple.0, tuple.1 as! Bool)

case let x as Double:
    print("It's a Double")
    let doubleTuple = (tuple.0, tuple.1 as! Double)

case let x as NSDateFormatter:
    print("It's an NSDateFormatter")
    let dateFormatterTuple = (tuple.0, tuple.1 as! NSDateFormatter)

default:
    print("Unsupported type")
}
```

If the API returns `Any` and the tuple isn't guaranteed to be `(String, Any)`, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my main problem is that `Any` cannot be casted to a tuple of type `(Any, Any)`.

Comment: @Qbyte You can't do that. As I said, you can't convert a tuple to a different type. Adding `Any` as an intermediary doesn't change anything: you can only cast `Any` to the compound type that the tuple actually is.

Comment: This answer is correct – but your first example is wrong. In Swift, an `Int` *cannot* be cast to a `Double`, it has to be converted through using `Double`'s initialiser that accepts an `Int`. The reason `let nums : (Double, Double, Double) = (1, 5, 9)` works is that `1` `5` and `9` are integer *literals*, which can be used to construct a `Double` via its conformance to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`.

Comment: This just seems like a failure of the language, imo. What is the point of introducing tuples if they're not actually compatible with the other concepts of the language like inheritance? Object oriented principles state that a subclass must be able to be treated *as* its superclass. This is a key requirement for abstraction. Telling me to model it as a class or struct just seems like a cop-out. These half-baked language features are driving me nuts.

Answer (score -1):

The Swift compiler will enforce that you are explicit about your types. So if you declare it as `(String, Bool)` it will not allow the conversion.

The following works as expected in Playground:

```
var specificTuple : (String, Bool) = ("Hi", false)
var generalTuple  : (Any, Any)     = ("Hi", false)

var gany = generalTuple
gany.1 = "there"
gany                           // (.0 "Hi", .1 "there")

var spany = specificTuple
spany.1 = "there"             // error
```

You can create the `(Any, Any)` tuple ad hoc but you will need to decompose it

```
var any : (Any, Any)  = (specificTuple.0, specificTuple.1)
any.1 = "there"
any                          // (.0 "Hi", .1 "there")
```