# typecasting tuples in swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm trying without success to unwrap and cast multiple optionals via tuples. The strange thing is that unwrapping individual items works.
It has been suggested that I'm misusing the [downcast `as?` operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html),
and that's very likely, but I just can't see it.

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

```
class fooba {  }

func unwrapPair(a: AnyObject?, _ b:AnyObject?) {
    if let a = a as? fooba {
        // true
    }

    if let b = b as? fooba {
        // true
    }

    if let (a, b) = (a, b) as? (fooba, fooba) {
        // false!?!?
    }
}
unwrapPair(fooba(), fooba())
```

I don't *think* this is a duplicate of [tuple "upcasting"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270507),
because aren't I downcasting? In any case, explaining exactly how
they're duplicates would be illuminating and an answer in itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tuple "upcasting" in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270507/tuple-upcasting-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of separately trying to match each component with if-let combinations, you can just do the same in a more swift-y way:

```
switch (a, b) {
case (let a as String, _):
    // Do whatever you need to do with a
    return true
case (_, let b as String):
    // Do whatever you need to do with b
    return true
case (let a as NSNumber, let b as NSNumber):
    // Do whatever you need to do with a and b
    return false
default:
    return true
}
```

Note also that the type of downcast you are trying to do is currently impossible - look at this swift bug: [tuple 'as?' downcast broken](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1423)

Comment: Thank you! This worked, and as a bonus I was able to drop `AnyObject?` back to `Any?` and now `Int`s work as well as `fooba`s.