# Cannot express tuple conversion '([Subclass], Int, String)' to '([Superclass], Int, String)'

Tags: ios, swift

**Original**

In my project I have a `Iterator` class, which has a function:

```
func iterateItems<T: Items>(iterationItems: [T], removeItem: (T) -> Void, addItem: (T) -> Void, calculateEfficiency: () -> Void) -> [T] {

    ...
    return bestComposition as! [T]
}
```

And in its subclass `WPCalculator` I run it this way:

```
func iterateWPItems() -> [Items] {
    return iterateItems(iterationItems: WeaponItems.weaponItems, removeItem: removeWeaponItem, addItem: addWeaponItem, calculateEfficiency: calcWeaponDemage)
}
```

**New code**

Everything worked fine that way. Now I want to change the `iterateItems` function to this:

```
func iterateItems<T: Items>(iterationItems: [T], removeItem: (T) -> Void, addItem: (T) -> Void, calculateEfficiency: () -> Void) -> ([T], Int, String) {

    ...
    return (bestComposition as! [T], bestBuildCost, customMessage)
}
```

Then I updated `WPCalculator` accordingly:

```
func iterateWPItems() -> ([Items], Int, String) {
    return iterateItems(iterationItems: WeaponItems.weaponItems, removeItem: removeWeaponItem, addItem: addWeaponItem, calculateEfficiency: calcWeaponDemage)
}
```

> Now I get an error: Cannot express tuple conversion '([WeaponItems], Int,
>   String)' to '([Items], Int, String)'

The argument passed to `iterateWPItems` is an array of type `WeaponItems`, which is a subclass of `Items`, it worked fine in the original version, where Swift seems to have inferred the subclass-to-superclass conversion, but when I put it in a tuple in the new code, it doesn't work.

Why is that? How do I solve this problem?

**Edit:**

`WeaponItems`:

```
class WeaponItems: Items {

var weaponPower, attackSpeed, criticalChance, criticalDamage, armorPierce: Double

init(name: String, index: Int, price: Int, weaponPower: Double = 0, attackSpeed: Double = 0, criticalChance: Double = 0, criticalDamage: Double = 0, armorPierce: Double = 0, image: UIImage){

    self.weaponPower = weaponPower
    self.attackSpeed = attackSpeed
    self.criticalChance = criticalChance
    self.criticalDamage = criticalDamage
    self.armorPierce = armorPierce
    super.init(name: name, index: index, price: price, image: image)
}
...
}
```

`Items`:

```
class Items {

let name: String
let index: Int
let price: Int
let image: UIImage

init(name: String, index: Int, price: Int, image: UIImage) {
    self.name = name
    self.index = index
    self.price = price
    self.image = image
}
...
}
```

Comment: In which Swift version do you get this?  A simple test in Swift 3 works fine for me.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov it's Swift 3

Comment: What your `Items` and `WeaponItems` look like then?

Comment: @AntonBronnikov please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has indeed to do with the fact that although Swift can implicitly convert `[WeaponItems]` into `[Items]`, it fails to do so when these types come as the components of tuples.  E.g. see this: [Tuple "upcasting" in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270507/tuple-upcasting-in-swift)

There are several ways to "solve" this problem.

Easiest is:

```
func iterateWPItems() -> ([Items], Int, String) {
    let (composition, cost, message) = iterateItems(iterationItems: WeaponItems.weaponItems, removeItem: removeWeaponItem, addItem: addWeaponItem, calculateEfficiency: calcWeaponDemage)
    return (composition, cost, message)
}
```

Alternatively, you can change `iterateItems` to return just the tuple you expect, that is `([Items], Int, String)`:

```
func iterateItems<T: Items>(iterationItems: [T], removeItem: (T) -> Void, addItem: (T) -> Void, calculateEfficiency: () -> Void) -> ([Items], Int, String) {
    ...
    return (bestComposition as! [Items], bestBuildCost, customMessage)
}
```

Better still, from the way it looks I do not see why `iterateItems` has to be a generic method.  If that's indeed the case, then simply changing it to:

```
func iterateItems(iterationItems: [Items], removeItem: (Items) -> Void, addItem: (Items) -> Void, calculateEfficiency: () -> Void) -> ([Items], Int, String) {
    ...
    return (bestComposition as! [Items], bestBuildCost, customMessage)
}
```

.. should also help.

Comment: Yeah you are right it worked, the last approach is the best, thank you!