# Cannot pattern match a tuple of subtypes

Tags: swift, pattern-matching

Consider the following code:

```
protocol P {}

struct A: P {}


func match(_ l: P, _ r: P) {
  switch l {
    case is A:
      print("l is A")

    default:
      print("failed to match single value")
  }

  switch (l, r) {
    case is (A, A):
      print("(l, r) is (A, A)")

    case (_, _) as (A, A):
      print("(l, r) is (A, A)")

    default:
      print("failed to match tuple")
  }
}

match(A(), A())
```

Running this in playground produces the following output:

```
l is A
failed to match tuple
```

Apparently pattern matching a tuple of subtypes does not work. Is this a bug or a feature? If it is the latter, it would be interesting to know why.

Comment: Related: [Tuple “upcasting” in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270507/tuple-upcasting-in-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**Update:** In Swift 3.1, available with Xcode 8.3 beta, your code now behaves as expected.)

This is a bug, and is tracked by [SR-1423](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1423). However, according to that report, the issue has now been fixed on the master branch of the Swift repository, so all should be well when Swift 3.1 comes around ([expected release date](https://swift.org/blog/swift-3-1-release-process/) is "spring of 2017").

However, until then, a simple solution is just to check the type of each element in the tuple individually:

```
switch (l, r) {
case (is A, is A):
    print("(l, r) is (A, A)")
default:
    print("failed to match tuple")
}
```

Or if you need to use `l` and `r` in the `case`:

```
switch (l, r) {
case let (l as A, r as A):
    print("(\(l), \(r)) is (A, A)")
default:
    print("failed to match tuple")
}
```